# DOTWeen doesn't want to start a second time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dotween

I'm trying to make an object input animation using DOTWeen Pro. I test, and call the same function twice, the second time with a small delay.The first time the objects enter and make the animation ok, the second time it resets and no longer enters, what would be the problem?
I attach a section of code below. Thanks in advance.

```
    public void Start()
{
    SpawnStuffs();
    Invoke("SpawnStuffs", 2f);
}
    private void SpawnStuffs()
{
    int goodPlace = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, stuffSequences.Length - 1);
    stuffSequences[goodPlace].setCurrentChildIndex(friendlyStuffRandomnes.getRandom());
    List<Tween> moveFindTweenList = DOTween.TweensById("MOVE");
    for (int i = 0; i < stuffSequences.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i != goodPlace)
        {
            stuffSequences[i].setCurrentChildIndex(unfriendlyStuffRandomnes.getRandom());
        }
        stuffSequences[i].transform.position = stuffSequenceStartPositions[i];
        stuffSequences[i].transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
        moveFindTweenList[i].ForceInit();
        moveFindTweenList[i].Play().SetDelay(i * 0.05f);
        stuffSequences[i].CurrentChild.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().maskInteraction = SpriteMaskInteraction.VisibleInsideMask;
        masks[i].SetActive(true);
    }
    count = 0;
}
```

[image: Dotween setting]

Comment: You need to "Rewind" the tween. Think in a way that animation reaches the end (completes) and you need to tell that it needs to go to the start by using "Rewind" function. You can do this in code or via inspector. Turn OnComplete in events and link the DO Tween Animation component and choose the "Rewind" function.

Comment: thanks, go. I just added the Rewind function before ForceInit.